# mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.2.0

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am getting this error

> mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs,
>   Version=3.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx' or one
>   of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

while running azure function application on VS2019. I have added packages for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core & Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask. Also have updated all references to latest version.

Comment: Even though you add references. sometimes there won't be DLL s added in the working location. Please check whether all the referenced DLL s are available in the running location.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably hitting [Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk#333](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/333), You're also need to add the following to  csproj file to work around that .NET Core 3.0 SDK bug:

```
<Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
  <Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />
</Target>
```

This line should be taking care of that:  `<Exec Command="move $(PublishDir)\runtimes $(PublishDir)\bin" />`